# Re-recognize a harddisk in a Sharkoon Quickport Duo II after boot

Tags: debian, boot, hard-disk

I'm running Debian 8.6. The Sharkoon box is connected via e-sata cable. The harddisk I want to access holds an lvm2 logical volume [which was created with a different machine, also debian 8.6].
My problem is this: I can access the disk if the Sharkoon device was switched  **on before** I powered on the computer. If it is done the other way round I **can't**.
Is there a command that saves me from rebooting?

Answer (score 0):

Become root (of course) e.g. via `sudo -s`.

Then run:

```
pvscan
vgscan
vgchange –available y
lvscan
```

`pvscan` looks for any LVM physical volume on attached devices.

`vgscan` then looks for any LVM volume groups on discovered physical volumes.

`vgchange -available y` marks the discovered volume groups as active.

`lvscan` finally looks for logical volumes in the discovered volume groups.

Now the logical volumes should be available under /dev/mapper/volgroup-logvol (where of course `volgroup-logvol` depends on your config).

These steps are basically performed during booting which is why you can access the logical volumes directly when the drive was available during boot.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late but this solution doesn't work for me. Maybe here's another problem hidden.
I did further investgations and saw (purely by chance, using 'df') that the root filesystem once is at /dev/sda1 (Sharkoon 'off' while booting) while next time it is at /dev/sdb1 (Sharkoon 'on' while booting).
With Sharkoon 'off' during boot I'm not even able to see the hd with 'fdisk -l' after turning the device on.
It's a complete riddle to me. I  now think it could have to todo with BIOS settings
but I'm not very expirienced at that topic.
Otherwise your solution is correct.

Comment: Check what happens if you first unplug the eSATA cable, then turn it on, then insert the eSATA cable. Also check the `dmesg -ew` output for any messages during this action (i.e. first start `dmesg -ew`, then plug in the cable).

Comment: No change. I followed your instructions. `dmesg -ew` simply remains silent.

Comment: Looks like a hardware issue with your esata port, unfortunately.